# If statement inside jQuery function not recognized

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am working with the `fullcalendar` script. When I load the calendar I want to check if there are some variables set. I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    if(mes != '') {
       mes=1;
    },

    editable: false,  
    header: {  
        left: 'prev,next ',  
        center: 'title',  
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'  
    },  

    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    buttonText: {  
        today:    'hoy',  
        month:    'mes',  
        week:     'semana',  
        day:      'dia'  
    },  

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        //al hacer clic en el evento, si estamos en el mes o semana que vaya al día
        var vista=calendar.fullCalendar('getView').name;

        if (vista=="month" | vista=="agendaWeek") {
            //si estamos en vista de mes o semana, cambiamos a la del día
            calendar.fullCalendar( 'changeView', "agendaDay");
            calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', calEvent.start );
        } else {
            //si estamos en el vista de día 
            var color =calEvent.color;
            var id_evento=calEvent._id;

            document.form2.id_eve.value = id_evento;
            document.forms["form2"].submit();
            var ano=calEvent.year;
            var mes=calEvent.month;
            var dia=calEvent.day;
        }
    }
    });
});
```

But it does not work, the statement is:

```
if(mes != '') {
    mes=1;
},
```

It says I have a syntax error. How could I fix this and check if my variables are set? I also tried with:

```
if(typeof mes != 'undefined')
```

But this gives the same error.

Comment: I have no idea how that statement could be wrong, because it looks correct to me, but the other if statement, `if (vista=="month" | vista=="agendaWeek"){`, should be using `||` instead of `|`

Comment: Object [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals)/[initialisers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5), like the `{ ... }` being passed to `fullCalendar()`, don't support statements. They should only contain key/value pairs.

Comment: thanks, It was an error posting here, still I get the error where i have the first if =( @jonhopkins

Comment: So how can I do to check if I have those variables so I know what date to initialize the calendar? @JonathanLonowski

Comment: @MarianaHernandez You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like some have suggested if the value is meant for a particular key or move the `if` block to be before `var calendar ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use an `if` statement in the middle of data. That won't work.

You can achieve the same effect this way:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  'mes': (typeof(mes) === 'undefined') ? 1 : mes,

  // ...
```

Comment: I think you're onto something there (e.g., in terms of what the OP's end goal is, which I couldn't figure out in the time I gave it).

Comment: I want to initialize the calendar in a specific date after I POST the form, but if it is the first time loading the calendar, i want it to star a the current date. Still this answers are making the calendar not load  @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @MarianaHernandez: As I said in my answer, you'll need to use one of the calendars callbacks for that. The syntax Paul and I are pointing you to is valid (and not why the calendar isn't loading), but I suspect you really want to handle a callback the calendar makes when it loads (I don't know this plugin) and handle it there.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put `if` statements in object initializers.

It's unclear where or when you want to do this check, but basically it can't be in the initializer of the object that you're passing into `fullCalendar`. It can be in code before that, or code in one of the callbacks.

If there's a property in the object you're creating that you want to give one value to if `mes` is `!= ''` and a different value otherwise, you *can* do that:

```
thePropertyName:  mes != '' ? "value1" : "value2",
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant have the if there, you can either do it outside your initializer, or just use something like `mes != '' ? mes : 1,`